# perl hash with array

Tags: arrays, perl, perl-data-structures

I did same hash like this:

```
my %tags_hash;
```

Then I iterate some map and add value into @tags_hash:

```
if (@tagslist) {

        for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#tagslist; $i++) {
            my %tag = %{$tagslist[$i]};


            $tags_hash{$tag{'refid'}} = $tag{'name'};


        }}
```

But I would like to have has with array, so when key exists then add value to array.
Something like this:

e.g. of iterations

```
1, 
key = 1
value = "good"

{1:['good']}


2, 
key = 1
value = "bad"

{1:['good', 'bad']}

3, 
key = 2
value = "bad"

{1:['good', 'bad'], 2:['bad']}
```

And then I want to get array from the key:

```
print $tags_hash{'1'};

Returns: ['good', 'bad']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extended example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $hash = {}; # hash ref

#populate hash
push @{ $hash->{1} }, 'good';
push @{ $hash->{1} }, 'bad';
push @{ $hash->{2} }, 'bad';

my @keys = keys %{ $hash }; # get hash keys

foreach my $key (@keys) { # crawl through hash
  print "$key: ";
  my @list = @{$hash->{$key}}; # get list associate within this key
  foreach my $item (@list) { # iterate through items
    print "$item ";
  }
  print "\n";
}
```

output:

```
1: good bad 
2: bad
```

Comment: +1: Though the last 7 lines can be simplified by saying `print "$_: " . join (" ", @{$hash->{$_}}) ."\n" foreach (keys %$hash);`

Comment: @jaypal good idea, but I tought output could be a little bit complex if compared with what I suggested for it. Actually desired output is in the form: `{1:['good', 'bad'], 2:['bad']}` so this form is a little trickier to handle with `join function`.

Answer (score 1):

So the value of the hash element to be an array ref. Once you have that, all you need to do is push the value onto the array.

```
$hash{$key} //= [];
push @{ $hash{$key} }, $val;
```

Or the following:

```
push @{ $hash{$key} //= [] }, $val;
```

Or, thanks to autovivification, just the following:

```
push @{ $hash{$key} }, $val;
```

For example,

```
for (
   [ 1, 'good' ],
   [ 1, 'bad' ],
   [ 2, 'bad' ],
) {
   my ($key, $val) = @$_;
   push @{ $hash{$key} }, $val;
}
```